# Design pattern for binding metrics to dependencies at run-time

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm creating a Spark plugin which collects around 100 metrics for a spark job in real-time. For some metrics, we can get it from different dependencies (such as the Spark API and Prometheus), and I need to bind each metric to a dependency call at run-time (based on factors such as user configuration, dependency availability, etc). I'm struggling to figure out a design pattern for this such that it can be created in an OOP language like Java. Furthermore, I'm trying to avoid a use of a map structure, because I want to avoid any memory overhead wherever possible. The `adapter` class to collect the metrics would look something like this.

```java
SparkMetricAdapter {
    
    // constructor with dependencies(?)
    // substitute the dependency at runtime.

    public Metric IOTime() {
     return dependency.callMethod();
    }

    public Metric CPUTime() {
      return dependency.callMethod(); 
    }



}
```

The problem here is, that I would have to specify a 'map' structure for each metric, such that it substitutes the `dependency` instance **for each metric individually**. Is there an elegant way to do this using interfaces without the need of an auxillary data structure?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to define a `Map<String, Supplier<Metric>>` or even a `list of Pair<String, Supplier<Metric>>`. As a result, you'll be able to iterate through these pairs and evaluate the suppliers whenever you want. Finally, you can collect everything back to a map:

```java
private final List<Pair<String, Supplier<Metric>>> metrics = List.of(
    Pair.of("IOTime", dependency1::methodX),
    Pair.of("CPUTime", dependency1::methodY),
    Pair.of("GPUComputeTime", dependency2::methodZ)
);


public Map<String, Metric> metrics() {
    return metrics.stream()
        .collect(toMap(p -> p.getLeft(), p -> p.getRight().get()));
}
```